# Autowiring in typescript

Tags: typescript, autowired

I have an input message which has to be compared with the one existing in my DB and generate specific domain events.

An implementation for this in java will be creating an abstract class with a method to process and generate events. All classes which inherit this will provide their specific implementations. I am autowiring AbstractDetector and hence all its child classes will get become eligible candidates and get added to the list as below

```
@Autowired
public Processor(
            List<AbstractDetector> detectors, 
            ) {
        this.detectors = detectors;

    }
```

Then iterating through detectors and calling process method in each of them will create my domain events.

Please suggest how to implement the same in typescript.

Comment: we'd need more than just the behaviour. There are depedency injection libraries in javascript but solution (as in java) can be very strongly influenced by the framework you are using.

Comment: We are using nodejs with typescript. Please suggest an alternate approach without using dependency injection libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry but recommending libraries is not what SO is for. A simple google search will give you that. :)